# Recommendation for Laptop with RTX Graphics

Tags: laptop, graphics-cards

### Intro

I have seen some information scattered online about various new laptops that are bound to be released on 29th January 2019, which feature the new NVIDIA RTX graphics cards. However, each online source I stumble upon seems to concentrate on only one brand, and the concrete specs and pricing are hard to uncover in a wall of blabbering in the articles...

---

### Desired Laptop Specs

I am interested in all RTX laptops to be released on Jan 29th with the following specs:

- 15" display (preferably, but might consider a 17" notable mention)
- i7 cpu (prefer stronger single process performance over parallel processing)
- 16GB RAM or more
- 256+GB SSD & 1+TB HDD (might adjust after the fact)
- 144Hz screen (preferably, not a deal breaker)
- NVIDIA RTX 2070 (or 2080, prefer to avoid Max-Q and Optimus if possible)
- Ships within the US
- Budget centered around $2000, $3000 reluctantly.

**I'm interested in brands, model designs and pricing of any laptop that approximately fits the above criteria. Thanks for any suggestion!**

---

### Resources/Articles

- Ultrabookreview has a list of all upcoming RTX and RTX Max-Q laptops, with more details to be filled in at a later time when it becomes available:

  > https://www.ultrabookreview.com/24319-laptops-nvidia-rtx-2080/
- Similarly, techwalls has a list of all RTX 2080 laptops, with pictures and specs:

  > https://www.techwalls.com/nvidia-geforce-rtx-2080-laptops/

Comment: That's a _beast_ of a machine, even for a desktop. Any reason you're looking for laptops rather than a desktop?

Comment: @ArtOfCode I'd like it to be portable, which is a big deal for me. Currently I'm considering the MSI GE75 Raider with RTX2080 (it's 17" screen in 15" form factor), but sadly it is still unclear when it is going to actually come out...

Comment: Why avoid Optimus..?

Comment: @RubyJunk It may be a bit weird, but some time down the road I may consider running linux on that laptop, and optimus is notoriously badly supported on linux, which is some hassle I'd like to avoid if possible.